# Shorten the IF condition for 2 variables (same comparison)

Tags: python, if-statement

Following is what I need to do:

```
if ((a<100 and a>-100) and (b<100 and b>-100)):

#i.e., if both a and b lie in the interval (-100,100)
```

Was wondering if I can write this in a shorter way.

UPD: Found the following way. Anything shorter than this? (This isn't much short for only 2 variables though)

```
if all((x > -100 and x < 100) for x in (a,b))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write

```
(a<100 and a>-100)
```

as

```
-100 < a < 100
```

Thus you can simplify your expression to

```
if -100 < a < 100 and -100 < b < 100:
    #Do things
```

since your limits are symmetric about zero a further simplification could be to use:

```
abs(a) < 100
```

Comment: I miss these kind of things  when programming in Java. ( the `-100 < a < 100` thing). Sooner or later I will start using python

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
if abs(a) < 100 and abs(b) < 100:
    # do work
```

or

```
if all(abs(x) < 100 for x in (a,b))
```

Comment: I should have use abs(), I understand. I'm trying to shorten it the other way though.
Something like abs(a),abs(b)<100

Answer (score 1):

Here's the most terse I could make ;-)

```
from operator import lt

all(map(lt, [a,-a,b,-b], [100]*4))
```

Comment: You have my +1 for your imagination. But it seems that this is not the ideal solution for the OP.